# Enabling mod_deflate on plesk 12.0.18

Tags: php, plesk, mod-deflate

I wanted to enable `mod_deflate` on the web site to reduce the size of pages. I read that i have to edit the `.htaccess` file in order to enable it, but i can't find this file.

The site is hosted on a remote server, running plesk 12.0.18 on Windows.

Comment: You'll have to create it, this file is not genearted by default

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new text file, then rename it to .htaccess.

You may then enter the code e.g.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>
```